# Variable value is not reset after session cleanup for sessionscoped bean

Tags: session, jsf, scope, actionlistener

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Buy" styleClass="button-buy" actionListener="#{basketCount.incrementBasketCount}" immediate="true">
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

jsf2 part:

```
 <li class="basket">    
  #{basketCount.basketCount}
 </li>
```

faces-config:

```
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>basketCount</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>main.BasketCount</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

simple bean for action listening:

```
package main;

import java.io.Serializable;

    public class BasketCount implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -4576074045587545642L;

     int inBasketCount = 0;

     public void incrementBasketCount(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {
      inBasketCount++;
     }

     public int getBasketCount() {
      return inBasketCount;
     }

    }
```

use case:
**1.** click on "Buy" button
**2.** content of basket is incremented
**3.** click Shift-Ctrl-Del (clean cookie and cache) in FF and Refresh
**4.** counter of basket remained same

As I understand, session scope specifies,that this counter (step **2**) will be incremented in session scope only, and after cookies,cache clean up should be resetted?

The problem,that it does not.

Comment: And you don't have `JSESSIONID` attribute in your URL?

Comment: Probably your testing methodology was plain wrong. Did you check the request and response headers? (Firebug, etc) Did you debug the session creation? (Eclipse, HttpSessionListener, etc)

Comment: i was inattentive JSESSIONID exists,but not always displayed un URL.the problem is not actual any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by providing persistent cookies